# View being drawn upside down in iOS simulator, status bar orientation not properly detected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I am drawing a view on the iPad that only supports landscape orientations, however sometimes in the iOS simulator the view is drawn upside down and the iPad status bar is in portrait mode. When I rotate the device in the simulator, everything behaves normally, it's just the initial load that is weird.  I'm setting up my view using CGRect and use the standard iOS coordinate system.

My autorotation method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was that a typo in your code snippet; use "||", not "|", so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Comment: Or even better yet use `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`

Comment: I corrected the bitwise OR typo, and I am not experiencing this issue when I test on a device, but it still happens in the simulator.